# Merging borders of 2 divs on hover over

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div elements. First element is visible to the user, and when the user hovers over it, he is shown the remaining elements. On hovering over, I want to remove common borders of both these div elements.

I tried adding this css to the top div element so as to remove its border on hover over and increase its z - index such that it covers the top part of below div. But it is not working. Need help in getting this done.

Without hover:

```
 __________________
|                  |  
|__________________|
```

With hover (currently with above mentioned CSS):

```
 __________________
|                  |  
|__________________|__________________
|                                    |
|____________________________________|
```

Required on hover (this is what it should look like after removing common border):

```
 __________________
|                  |  
|                  |__________________
|                                     |
|_____________________________________|
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/fqw63Lzn/1/

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this or add related html code.

Comment: @Siguza I know about border-bottom and border-top property. This is not my use case, here is the fiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/fqw63Lzn/1/

Comment: @SrinivasPai Here is the fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/fqw63Lzn/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little **hack** can help us. It's not very elegant.
Don't know what you are trying to do, but it should works.
It's basically a div with the same dimensions of a border and background of list background color that goes over the parent border.

```css
.topTabButton {
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hack {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: white;
}
.itemList {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 12;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.enclose:hover .itemList {
  display: block;
  z-index: 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="enclose">
  <div class="topTabButton" id="topTabButton1">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </div>
  <div class="itemList" id="itemList1" style="width: 60%">
    <div class="hack"></div>
    <div class="list">
      <div>
        <div>sorry, changed to divs</div>
        <div>I think that tables can work it out too</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain your perplexities? I see that my snippet result is like draft the OP proposed. thank you @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D did you go with the mouse on hover the ABC text?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. This did solve the issue. Also the use case here was a menu to be shown on hover over. I needed the borders to be merged.